# Javascript getDay() function?

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to check the day and display the day name like Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday etc.

```
  function getDayDisplay(fullYear){

            var tmpArray = new Array();
            tmpArray[0] = "Sunday";
            tmpArray[1] = "Monday";
            tmpArray[2] = "Tuesday";
            tmpArray[3] = "Wednesday";
            tmpArray[4] = "Thrusday";
            tmpArray[5] = "Friday";
            tmpArray[6] = "Saturday";
            for(var i=0;i<tmpArray.length;i++){

                if(fullYear.getDay() == i){
                    alert(tmpArray[i]);
                }
            }
        }

         var indDate = new Date();
         indDate.setFullYear(2016,06,27);
        getDayDisplay(indDate);
```

Can some one please let me know why the above code result `Wednesday`  while when i am giving  `var indDate = new Date();` and not setting fullYear `setFullYear()` it is giving `Monday`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can some one please let me know why the above code result Wednesday
>   while when i am giving  var indDate = new Date(); and not setting
>   fullYear setFullYear() it is giving Monday.

Because when you do

```
indDate.setFullYear(2016,06,27);
```

you are actually setting month of `July` not `June` since month index starts from `0`, so 6 is `July` not `June`. Hence `indDate.getDay()` returns `3` not `1`.

Comment: According to API The `getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date`. and not the Month .

Comment: @SubodhJoshi yes and 27th July is a wednesday.